# Define service or action using adapted c++ message

Tags: ros, action, service, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've took a class of my existing code and adapted it using this: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes
It all works correctly. However, I would like to be able to define services and actions having this message as part of their definitions. If I simply write the .srv or .action files and use the name of the adapted type, it is not able to find it.

Is it possible to make the service/action generators to assume that the C++ version of a message already exist and not require a corresponding .msg file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195505/define-service-or-action-using-adapted-c++-message/) by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to add another way of solving this problem which I found out, by defining services using adapted types, as it is done for adapting types for messages, which avoids requiring the message generator.
A brief explanation is here: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp_traits/html/service__traits_8h_source.html

---

Originally posted by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) with karma: 122 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; you cannot use a custom serialized type within the ROS message/service/action language.

The reason that this is not possible is that the code generator has to be able to generate code for multiple languages including C++ , Python, Lisp, and others.

What you can do is to have a series of matching msg/srv/action files and C++ classes that serialize to the same format.

The example you link to serializes the same as a geometry_msgs/Vector3, for example, and this preserves its interoperability with Python and the other languages that are supported by ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1